# Accessing the configure closure from a gradle extension

Tags: plugins, gradle

I'm writing a plugin in which do something like the following:

```
project.extensions.create('myExtension', new MyExtension(project))
```

where `MyExtension` is the class that defines my new functionality.

Now, in `gradle.build` I can do this:

```
myExtension {
    // configure cool stuff
}
```

What I would like to do now, is to "consume" a couple of the things in this configure closure, and pass the rest of the closure as-is to a task I defined, using `project.configure(myTask, closure)`. However, I have no idea how to

1. Access the configure closure from the `MyExtension` class.
2. "Consume" some of the closure, i.e. access some of the properties on the closure and then strip them, leaving another closure which has all the untouched things but nothing else

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated =)

Answer (score 1):

It's not how extensions work. The closure gets evaluated immediately in order to configure the extension object. After that, the closure is gone. Typically, a plugin will use the (information contained in the) extension object to further configure tasks.

PS: It's `extensions.create('myExtension', MyExtension, project)`, not `project.extensions.create('myExtension', new MyExtension(project))`.

Comment: OK. But what way would you then recommend for accomplishing my goals? The extension will configure a copy task (or rather a custom task that inherits from `Copy`) but also do some other stuff, and I would like to avoid having to implement wrappers for every single way to configure a `Copy` operation. Should the extension extend `Copy`? Does that make sense?

Comment: Without more context it's hard to say, but configure a `Copy` task *and* do some other stuff is probably not the way to go. Extensions are meant to be a higher level of abstraction than tasks, covering the 80% case. Generally, it isn't recommended to inherit from Gradle task classes; instead, the custom task class should expose its own API and, if necessary, *delegate* to the `project.copy` method. Alternatively, a custom plugin could bring on both a `Copy` task and a custom task, and make one depend on the other.

Comment: OK, some context: What I'm trying to do is simply a more customizable release plugin, which handles both version numbering and deciding from where, and where to, copy the build output when releasing. While writing this comment I realized it might be nice to wrap the copy task rather than extend it, and add methods to the extension type for forwarding a closure to the copy task. Does this make sense? Is it more "gradle-y"?

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is to call a method on your extension and provide the "configuration" as a closure. So instead of

```java
// build.gradle

myExtension {
    // configure cool stuff
}
```

you write

```java
// build.gradle

myExtension.config {
    // configure cool stuff
}
```

The according method in your extension class would look like this:

```java
// MyExtension.groovy

class MyExtension {
    Project project

    MyExtension(Project project) {
        this.project = project
    }

    def config(Closure cl) {
        // Do stuff with the closure
    }
}
```

However, as the whole closure is forwarded to your own code, you lose all the evaluation Gradle normally does with the configuration closure.