# Are pmd, repositories etc tasks in Gradle

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I am creating basic custom tasks in Gradle and learning how to extend them to do more complicated actions (Learning from here: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html).

One of my reference projects, which I am extending to learn Gradle looks something like this

```
// pmd config
pmd {
    ignoreFailures = false
    reportsDir = file("$globalOutputDir/pmd")
    toolVersion = toolVersions.pmdVersion
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

task listSubProjects{
    doLast{
        println 'Searching in root dir `'
    }
}
```

My question is around the pmd and repositories sections and why they don't have a clear qualifier like "task" on them but my listSubProjects requires a task qualifier? Are these inherited tasks from plugins and don't need a task qualifier?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17360544/accessing-the-configure-closure-from-a-gradle-extension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blocks that you see are [task extensions](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html#sec:getting_input_from_the_build), also [discussed here](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-to-pass-parameters-to-a-plugin-during-apply/22144/3).

A plugin creator can define extensions to allow users to configure a plugin:

```
// plugin code
class GreetingPluginExtension {
    // default value
    String message = 'Hello from GreetingPlugin'
}

// plugin code
class GreetingPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    void apply(Project project) {
        // Add the 'greeting' extension object
        def extension = project.extensions.create('greeting', GreetingPluginExtension)
        // Add a task that uses configuration from the extension object
        ...
    }
}
```

In `project.extensions.create('greeting',...` the `greeting` block to be used later in build.gradle files is defined.

Then in user build.gradle files

```
apply plugin: GreetingPlugin

// Configure the extension
greeting.message = 'Hi from Gradle'

// Same effect as previous lines but with different syntax
greeting {
    message = 'Hi from Gradle'
}
```

Often the name of the extension is chosen to be the same as the plugin and/or the task, which can make things confusing.